# Populating indexes with elasticsearch by Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, doctrine-orm

I'm newbie in elasticsearch, I have installed and well configured symfony2 with elasticsearch by using FOSElasticaBundle.

The problem is that when I try to populate indexes by using the following command :

```
php app/console fos:elastica:populate  --verbose --no-reset
```

And when I achieve up to 70% in progress

11200/11200 [============================] 100% 5 secs

315000/415391 [=====================>------]  75%   1 hr

I got an **OUT OF MEMORY** Exception:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryException]                      
  Error: Out of memory (allocated -1371537408) (tried to allocate 54801 bytes)
```

I have also  tried the --sleep and --offset options to overcome the problem but without success. 
In addition I have removed completly serializer from the config file.

Any Idea ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Adding --no-debug reduces memory usage to some extend

```
app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-debug
```

Or reducing the number of objects retrieved by

```
  persistence:
    driver: orm
    model: Application\Bundle\Entity\Article
    provider:
      batch_size: 100
```

See the following issue for more information:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/issues/153